# Деепричастие "исходя из"

Tags: запятые, деепричастия

Аргумент, что оборот "исходя из" можно опустить, является крайне ненадежным, так как опустить его возможно почти что в каждом из примеров Розенталя в обеих случаях.

Выделим два противоположных примера, в одном из которых есть обособление, в другом - нет.

1) Таблица составлена исходя из полученных сведений.

2) Калькулятор составил расчёт, исходя из представленных ему данных.

Вторым аргументом, который может разграничить эти два случая, выступает производитель действия. Розенталь указал, что если оборот "исходя из" относится к производителю действия, который может "исходить из чего-то", то оборот следует обособить, причем им может быть как определенное, так и неопределенное лицо.

Вопрос: почему в первом примере отсутствует запятая, если действие в нем произведено неопределенным лицом, которое может исходить из "полученных сведений"?

Answer (score 2):

1) ***Таблица составлена исходя из полученных сведений.***

2) ***Калькулятор составил расчёт, исходя из представленных ему 
данных.***

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113

Примечание. Одиночное деепричастие или деепричастный оборот не обособляется:
5) если **деепричастие утратило глагольное значение**.

Это значит, что деепричастие **приобретает статус другой части речи (производного предлога),** возможна замена предлогом-синонимом: *Таблица составлена в соответствии с полученными сведениями.*

Во втором предложении **значение действия сохраняется**, возможна такая замена: *Калькулятор составил расчёт, используя представленные ему данные.*

Поэтому здесь не столько важен формальный прием (***исходя из*** можно опустить), сколько важно  наличие или отсутствие действия для этой деепричастной формы.